# Prove function is a metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $d((x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)) = |x_2 - y_2|$ if $x_1 = y_1$ and $d((x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)) = |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2| + |y_2|$ otherwise. I want to prove that it is a metric.

I can do it only by considering many cases which is quite lengthy. Can it be proven neatly?

Comment: The only longer part to prove is the triangle inequality. The rest of the conditions are trivial

Comment: I agree, triangle inequality is the main part.

Comment: See if https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52827/ answers your question

Comment: Yes it answers my question, thank you.